# Number of user profiles conflicts with number of active users

Tags: office-365, user-profile

I am in Office 365, and I can see that the number of active users in Office 365 is 5, there's no deleted users, nothing. When I go to SharePoint administration, I can see in user profiles that the number of profiles is 10, how can that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the list of accounts: Admin Center | SharePoint | User Profiles | Manage User Profiles you will see that there are additional System Accounts like those for support that also have access and create profiles.

Comment: thank you Matthew, how can I see these. I typed in the search box: system, and it didn't get anyone.

Comment: Try Searching for "I" or "support".